# Salesforce Outgoing message: SOAP response was a nack

Tags: laravel, salesforce, laravel-5, soapserver

I am integrating with an in-house system.  I have set up an outgoing message on one object and my web service is seeing the message every time I update a record.  My service is sending an true response, but the outgoing message delivery status is showing "SOAP response was a nack".

I have used wireshark to capture the request and the response on my web server.  This is what I see:

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <notifications xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
   <OrganizationId>00D00000000hfNqEAI</OrganizationId>
   <ActionId>04k370000004FsYAAU</ActionId>
   <SessionId xsi:nil="true"/>
   <EnterpriseUrl>https://na31.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/36.0/00D00000000hfNq</EnterpriseUrl>
   <PartnerUrl>https://na31.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/36.0/00D00000000hfNq</PartnerUrl>
   <Notification>
    <Id>04l370000006ISGAA2</Id>
    <sObject xsi:type="sf:Opportunity" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
     <sf:Id>00637000007h5uwAAA</sf:Id>
     <sf:AccountId>00100000003Qy45AAC</sf:AccountId>
     <sf:Name>Andrew Test</sf:Name>
     <sf:OwnerId>00500000006pE7kAAE</sf:OwnerId>
     <sf:StageName>Unqualified</sf:StageName>
    </sObject>
   </Notification>
  </notifications>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response: (HTTP/1.1 200 OK)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-NV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound"><SOAP-ENV:Body><Ack>true</Ack></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Can anyone see what is causing the response to fail?

Answer (score 1):

Your response message doesn't conform to the format described by the WSDL, it should be

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
   <notificationsResponse xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
     <Ack>true</Ack>
   </notificationsResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

note the additional notificationsResponse element, and the fact that this is in the OM xml namespace.